# Bound on sum of logarithms

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider a natural number $m$ and let $m_i, i=1,2,...,\lfloor{\sqrt{m}}\rfloor$ be natural numbers such that:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor{\sqrt{m}}\rfloor} m_i = m$$

My question regards the following sum:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor{\sqrt{m}}\rfloor} \log(\frac{m_i}{i}) $$

What can we say for the maximum size of this sum in comparison to $m$? Will it be of the order of $\sqrt{m}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the AM-GM inequality,
$$
\prod_i m_i 
\le \left(\frac{\sum_i m_i}{\lfloor \sqrt m \rfloor}\right)^{\lfloor \sqrt m \rfloor}
= \left(\frac{m}{\lfloor \sqrt m \rfloor}\right)^{\lfloor \sqrt m \rfloor}
\approx (\sqrt m)^{\sqrt m}
$$
(I'm too tired to care about the floor thingy right now). Therefore
$$
\sum_i \log\frac{m_i}{i}
= \log\prod_i\frac{m_i}{i}
\le \log \frac{(\sqrt m)^{\sqrt m}}{(\sqrt m)!}
= \sqrt m \log (\sqrt m) - \log(\sqrt m)!
$$
From looking a bit on the wiki page for Stirling's approximation, we find
$$
\log n! = n\log n + \Theta(n)
$$
If we plug that into the above we get
$$
\sum_i \log\frac{m_i}{i} \in O(\sqrt m)
$$
Note also that the AM-GM inequality is an equality in case all the $m_i$ are equal. That means that the above order can be attained. So we have in the worst case
$$
\sum_i \log\frac{m_i}{i} \in \Theta(\sqrt m)
$$
i.e. we can't improve on the order in the general case. This was like you guessed! We can make the bound more precise by adding more terms of the Stirling approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k=\lfloor \sqrt{m}\rfloor$. The sum is
$$\sum_{i=1}^k\log\left(\frac{m_i}{i}\right)=\log\left(\frac{m_1m_2\cdots m_k}{k!}\right) $$
By AM-GM
$$m_1m_2\cdots m_k\leq \left(\frac{m_1+m_2+\cdots+m_k}{k}\right)^k=\left(\frac{m}{k}\right)^k $$
For $k!$, we need a lower bound. Among various options:
$$k!\geq \left(\frac{k}{e}\right)^k$$
Hence,
$$\frac{m_1m_2\cdots m_k}{k!}\leq\left(\frac{me}{k^2}\right)^k$$
$$\log\left(\frac{m_1m_2\cdots m_k}{k!}\right)\leq k\log\left(\frac{me}{k^2}\right)\leq\sqrt{m}\log\left(\frac{me}{k^2}\right)$$
Note that $m/k^2 \to 1$ as $m\to\infty$, so $\log\left(me/k^2\right)\to \log(e)=1$ and $\log\left(me/k^2\right)<2$ for sufficiently large $m$. Alternatively, you can try showing that $m/k^2\leq 4$ for all $m$, so $\log\left(me/k^2\right)\leq \log(4e)=\log(4)+1$. The point is to show that $\log\left(me/k^2\right)$ is bounded by a constant.